# Upload image post with Meteor

Tags: meteor

I would like upload image when i creat new post on Meteor. I've see CollectionFS, but it's deprecated.

Do you know other package for upload image ? Directly on my server ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

I did once custom code for this action (uploading image to server), but the issue is that meteor listening for every change made on server. And so the app refreshes by itself after the upload is made.

If you doesn't care about this, i could upload my code.

The solution might be to upload images somewhere out of meteor folder.

Also CollectionFS i think will live for a while. There are some meteor apps that uses it. (e.x. reactioncommerce).

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the packages tomi:upload-server and tomi:upload-jquery. It is actively developed and has multiple contributors.

Check it out on github here: https://github.com/tomitrescak/meteor-uploads

Note that this does upload to directories outside of the standard Meteor directories though, so keep that in mind and make sure your hosting provider will allow for that.